# jest mongoose causing memory leak

Tags: typescript, mongoose, async-await, jestjs

**UPDATED 2020-09-14**

I have an example testcase I have written. When I run this code, the testcase passes but it complains that the teordown hasn't happened properly and there is an open connection. Can anyone spot what it is:

## Approach 1 - memory leak

```js
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'mongoose';
import __MONGO_URI__ from './__MONGO_URI__';

let conn: Connection | null = null;

const getConnection: (MONGO_DB_NAME: string) => Promise<Connection> = async MONGO_DB_NAME => {
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = await createConnection(__MONGO_URI__, {
      dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME,
      bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
      bufferMaxEntries: 0, // and MongoDB driver buffering
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    });
  }
  return conn;
};

const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'mongo-test';
let db: Connection;

describe('mongo - connection test to ensure setup teardown', () => {
  beforeAll(async done => {
    db = await getConnection(MONGO_DB_NAME);
    done();
  });
  afterAll(async done => {
    if (conn) {
      await db.dropDatabase();
      await conn.close();
    }
    done();
  });
  it('true = true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Error:

> A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --runInBand --detectOpenHandles to find leaks.

If I strip it all back down just to this:

## Approach 2 - memory leak

```js
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'mongoose';
import __MONGO_URI__ from './__MONGO_URI__';

let conn: Connection | null = null;

const getConnection: (MONGO_DB_NAME: string) => Promise<Connection> = async MONGO_DB_NAME => {
  if (conn == null) {
    conn = await createConnection(__MONGO_URI__, {
      dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME,
      bufferCommands: false,
      bufferMaxEntries: 0,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useCreateIndex: true
    });
  }
  return conn;
};

const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'mongo-test';
let db: Connection;

describe('mongo - connection test to ensure setup teardown', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    db = await getConnection(MONGO_DB_NAME);
    console.log('db = ', db);
  });
  it('true = true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I still have the same problem

Or even doing it this way same problem:

## Approach 3 - memory leak

```js
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'mongoose';
import __MONGO_URI__ from './__MONGO_URI__';

let conn: Connection | null = null;

const getConnection: (MONGO_DB_NAME: string) => Promise<Connection | null> = MONGO_DB_NAME =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    if (conn == null) {
      conn = createConnection(__MONGO_URI__, {
        dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME,
        bufferCommands: false,
        bufferMaxEntries: 0,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
      });
      conn.on('connected', () => {
        console.log('connected?');
        resolve(conn);
      });
    }
    resolve(conn);
  });

const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'mongo-test';
let db: Connection;

describe('mongo - connection test to ensure setup teardown', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    db = await getConnection(MONGO_DB_NAME);
    console.log('db = ', db);
  });
  it('true = true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

This approach also has same problem

## Approach 4 - memory leak

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import __MONGO_URI__ from './__MONGO_URI__';

let conn: typeof mongoose;

const getConnection: (MONGO_DB_NAME: string) => Promise<typeof mongoose> = async MONGO_DB_NAME => {
  if (!conn) {
    conn = await mongoose.connect(__MONGO_URI__, {
      dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME,
      // bufferCommands: false,
      // bufferMaxEntries: 0,
      // useNewUrlParser: true,
      // useUnifiedTopology: true,
      // useCreateIndex: true
    });
  }
  return conn;
};

const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'mongo-test';
let db: typeof mongoose;

describe('mongo - connection test to ensure setup teardown', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    db = await getConnection(MONGO_DB_NAME);
    console.log('db = ', db);
  });
  it('true = true', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, what's the output of running with `--runInBand --detectOpenHandles`?

Comment: Is there no error output? `async` with `done` is an antipattern. Should be `async` alone. A problem could happen if dropDatabase failed and close wasn't reached.

Comment: --runInBand --detectOpenHandles doesn't actually show anything and gets stuck and doesn't exit testing

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks for the feedback. It is not the dropping db or closing connection that causes the memory leak. It is the actual creation of connection.  createConnection is causing the memory leak. If I strip down the code just to shi. Even if I remove async await on it.

Comment: It's not a connection itself causes a leak but the fact that it was opened and not closed. Mongoose connections can surely can be closed and they are used in Jest tests without problems. Approaches 2-4 don't have any value in isolating the problem because they don't even try to close a connection. Try it the way I suggested, get rid of `done` because it's faulty and can suppress errors. Debug that `await conn.close()` really was called. This is the only possible problem I see here.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thats it. It works. Thankyou. Will post my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

final solution - thanks: @EstusFlask

**getMongoConnection.ts**

```js
import { Connection, createConnection } from 'mongoose';
import __MONGO_URI__ from './__MONGO_URI__';

let conn: Connection | null = null;

const getConnection: (MONGO_DB_NAME: string) => Promise<Connection | null> = MONGO_DB_NAME =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    if (conn == null) {
      conn = createConnection(__MONGO_URI__, {
        dbName: MONGO_DB_NAME,
        bufferCommands: false,
        bufferMaxEntries: 0,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
      });
      conn.on('connected', () => {
        resolve(conn);
      });
    }
    resolve(conn);
  });

export default getConnection;
```

**mytest.test.ts**

```js
import { Connection } from 'mongoose';
import getConnection from './getMongoConnection';

let db: Connection | null;

const MONGO_DB_NAME = 'mongo-test';
const collectionName = 'users';

describe('mongo - connection test to ensure setup teardown', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    db = await getConnection(MONGO_DB_NAME);
  });
  afterAll(async () => {
    if (db) {
      await db.dropDatabase();
      await db.close();
    }
  });
  it('should insert a doc into collection', async () => {
    if (db) {
      const users = db.collection(collectionName);

      const mockUser = { _id: 'some-user-id', name: 'John' };
      await users.insertOne(mockUser);

      const insertedUser = await users.findOne({ _id: 'some-user-id' });
      expect(insertedUser).toEqual(mockUser);
    }
  });
});
```